# Mapbox GL JS - Remove fade in time for image overlay

Tags: javascript, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I am currently working with image overlays (.gif) in Mapbox GL JS to provide weather radar data. I need to set a loop to show the images in motion - but the image overlays have a "fade-in" effect and I would like that gone. How can I remove this so the images just turn on and off as quickly as possible with no fade-in or out?  I cannot find this in the API documentation, but it's possible I missed it somehow.

*Edit :  To be clear, I am just asking how to remove the fade-effects - not how to loop it or anything else - I can do that later.*

My code to add an overlay and source (that produces the default fade-effect) is currently :

```
topleftmapbox.addSource("source_KEWX_L2_CC", {
"type": "image",
"url": "images/KEWX_L2_CC.gif",
"coordinates": [


[-102, 33],  
[-94, 33],   
[-94, 26], 
[-102, 26]          

]
})




topleftmapbox.addLayer({
"id": "overlay_KEWX_L2_CC",
"source": "source_KEWX_L2_CC",
"type": "raster",
"raster-opacity": 0.9,
"layout": {"visibility": "visible"},
}, firstSymbolId)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the [`raster-fade-duration`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-raster-raster-fade-duration) property:

```
topleftmapbox.addLayer({
  "id": "overlay_KEWX_L2_CC",
  "source": "source_KEWX_L2_CC",
  "type": "raster",
  "paint": {
    "raster-opacity": 0.9,
    "raster-fade-duration": 0
  },
  "layout": {"visibility": "visible"},
}, firstSymbolId)
```

P.S. And yes, I recommend using the [`canvassource`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#canvassource) for animation.